# ReflectionException : Class PermissionsTableSeeder does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I want to use a roles plugin:
https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-roles#installation

i followed the installation guide but i keep getting an error that the classes i added in the database seeder dont exsist in the run

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call('PermissionsTableSeeder');
        $this->call('RolesTableSeeder');
        $this->call('ConnectRelationshipsSeeder');
        // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

I tried running composer dump-autoload
and everything else i found on the internet about this problem.

I also tried changing the code to:

```
public function run()
    {
        $this->call(PermissionsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(RolesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(ConnectRelationshipsSeeder::class);
        // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    }
```

I just can't seem to fix it.

**The full error**

[image]

Comment: Have you also tried running them separately, for example:

`php artisan db:seed --class=PermissionsTableSeeder`

Comment: @nakov Yes i did but, didn't work for me either..

Comment: What is the error that you get? Or simply the seed does not exist? Check the class name in the seeder, compare it with the filename does it match?

Comment: @nakov I get a ReflectionExceprion. The spelling is correct of the class names.

Comment: @nakov I've added a picture of the error i get in my question.

Comment: So in the same folder of the `DatabaseSeeder` the `PermissionsTableSeeder` class exists? Have you checked your `composer.json` file under the `autoload` key in the classmap, does it have `"database/seeds",`?

Comment: `"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },`

This is in the autoload

Comment: another thing that is left is the permission of the files. Make sure that they are writable and readable by your system. I don't have anything else to add.

Comment: @nakov They do have premission. Thanks for trying to help tough!

Comment: I meant system permission, like 755 or 777.. to be readable and writable. Just making sure that we both are on the same page.

Comment: btw, there was the same issue opened under the package [here](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-roles/issues/38). And I believe the latest solution left by a guy just 5 days ago might help

Comment: @nakov Removing the namespace in all the classes worked for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-roles/issues/38#issuecomment-488681065) helped. Solution on the same issue from the package itself.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the namespace Database\Seeds in all the classes used by the plugin fixed this issue! And my Seeders can seed now. The issues was in the package itself.